# How does WTP determine the Tomcat version

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I found in [Why won't the New Server Runtime dialog recognize my Linux installed version of Tomcat?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F) that:

> When identifying Tomcat 5.0.x, a servlet-api.jar is expected to be
>   present in the common/lib directory.

but my problem is I have a slightly modified Tomcat `7.0.30` and WTP thinks it's `5.1`

Where can I find a list of actual checks per Tomcat version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the anwser is here: https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.servertools/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core/tomcatcore/org/eclipse/jst/server/tomcat/core/internal/TomcatVersionHelper.java

Funny thing, they don't inspect the external file `CATALINA_BASE/lib/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties` as described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html